# How to discard/release message in MessageToMessageDecoder in Netty 4

Tags: java, netty

What should I do if inside my `decode` method i want to discard the message (for instance if this type of message is not supported by this client)? In other words I don't want to pass decoded message to another (business) handler.

To avoid memory leak and be consistent with decoder's implementation I should:

- use byteBuf.realease() / ReferenceCountUtil.release(byteBuf)
- invoke super.channelReadComplete() or some other function
- do something else?

Sample code:

```
public class MyMessageDecoder extends MessageToMessageDecoder {
    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        ....
        if (allowedTypes.containsKey(msgType)) {
            ...
            out.add(...);
        } else {
            //what to do here to discard this this message
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using netty 4.0.25 and my decoder is prepended with LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder (so MyMessageDecoder is receiving whole needed payload)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Releasing is done for you by the MessageToMessageDecoder itself. So the only thing you may want to do is throw an exception or something like this.

Comment: Thank you Norman. What if it is ByteToMessageDecoder? It is called many times as long as full payload is received so I can not just leave it as in the example above?